# Extract numbers only part in shell script

Tags: regex, linux, macos, powershell, shell

I need a help to extract a part of string into a variable with a shell script.

```
$STR=“ttysggjs364-hhe 1738.98”
```

I need `1738.98` in to a variable. How can I do this. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks

Comment: @shellter : This looks like bash / POSIX shell code to me. The OP is looking for a powershell solution.

Comment: @kalanmw : Why is this tagged "regex"? Also, define how your pattern looks like **in genreal**. Is there always a space in front of the number? Is the number always at the end? BTW, I don't think you need to specify linux and macos. Since you are using powershell, this should work the same on both platforms.

Comment: @shellter : It is perhaps an unusual choice for a shell, in particular if the target OS is Linux and MacOS (as the OP indicated), but I *do* know people who use Powershell as a shell (and of course then for scripting too).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the statement and as tagged "powershell", I would propose

```
$STR=“ttysggjs364-hhe 1738.98”
$expected_output=($str.Split(" "))[1]
```

Of course statement is that STR always has same pattern

Answer (score 1):

A regex can be used to capture the number. This assumes that there is whitespace before the number begins. This is PowerShell code that works on all specified platforms.

```
$STR = “ttysggjs364-hhe 1738.98”
$TheNumber = $STR -replace '.*\s([\d\.]+).*','$1'
```